# Making preserved samosa

Tags: food-preservation

Is it possible to keep a samosa which is ready to be fried, frozen for a week or more and edible? If so, what is the process? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It should be fine. These sorts of foods are commonly sold frozen in the USA and other countries and are easily reheatable in an oven or fryer. They should keep for some time sealed in a plastic container or bag when frozen

Freeze by placing in a single well-spaced layer on a tray, once frozen transfer to a more convenient container. To reheat/cook, heat fryer to correct temperature and fry for approx 5 min. An oven will take longer to cook.